# Compress a folder with internal complex folders tree and UTF-8 mixed languages files and formats for archive

Tags: compression, zip, tar, archiving, rar

I have a cloud folder on my hard-drive which I want to archive, in-order to do so I would like to compress it using best of choice compressor for that task :

1. Complex sub-tree of internal folders with very long paths names.
2. File names can be long as well (doc file names by office workers) in multi-languages
3. File internal content can be UTF-8 as well.
4. Large directory of several tens of GB's, should be splitted into parts.

I work on MacOSx (and hence Unix Bash).

What would be the preferred method to compress and archive such a folder ?
Tar ? Zip ? Other ?

What args do I need to provide it ?

Thank you!